# Prevent Entity Framework 5 from querying Information_Schema_Tables

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-5

With EF 4.1, you used to remove the IncludeMetadataConvention in order to prevent EF from querying for database metadata on every query.

In EF 5, I get a warning about IncludeMetadataConvention being obsolete, and in LinqPad, I can see that EF is now querying for migration history on every use.  I'm working on a database first project (but using POCO's and DbContext). I don't want the overhead of these extra queries.  How do I turn them off?

**Update**
I found that I can disable this on a per-dbContext basis by calling

```
System.Data.Entity.Database.SetInitializer<theDbContext>(null);
```

However, I would like to be able to disable initialization globally (Imagine a large app, and we want to ensure that we are not running these queries (and definitely not trying to create a database) when it is deployed for production.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to do it for every context type in your large application you can create some code which will go through all of your assemblies, find all types derived from `DbContext` and invoke that call through reflection for every found type.

Btw. since EF 4.3 you can also [change initializer from configuration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj556606.aspx) but it is still per context basis because people usually don't have more than one.

Comment: Well, now you've made be curious.  Does that imply that people usually just drag back objects that look exactly like their tables?  I had been using a context per module in a larger app as a way to have different projections of the same tables based on how they were used by the module.

Comment: Generally yes. You can always execute projection directly in the linq query.

Answer (score 1):

Why not put the code in the constructor of your DbContext classes?

I do this as well as set a parameter to disable AutoDetectChangesEnabled, LazyLoading & Proxy CreationEnabled.